# Two-way data binding of ComboBox to Properties.Settings

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to create a two-way `DataBinding` between an editable `ComboBox` and a setting `myStrings` in `Properties.Settings.Default` of the type `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`.

In my example code in `Properties.Settings.Default.myStrings` is loaded into the ComboBox exactly once. Updating and saving the settings with `button_Click()` (button named "fill") does not update the ComboBox. I must restart the app to see the changes.

Typing "Pear" in the ComboBox and saving the settings with `button_Click()` (button named "fill2"), doesn't do anything at all.

What I want to achieve is:

- ComboBox should always show the current content of `Properties.Settings.Default.myStrings`, even when the setting gets updated.
- `Properties.Settings.Default.myStrings` should be updated and saved when ComboBox loses focus.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:comboBoxDataBinding"
        xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:comboBoxDataBinding.Properties" x:Class="comboBoxDataBinding.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="212" Width="318">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Properties:Settings/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyStringsConverter x:Key="MyStringsConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding myStrings, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="fill2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,111,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace comboBoxDataBinding {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection sc = Properties.Settings.Default.myStrings;
            sc.Add("Apple");
            sc.Add("Orange");
            Properties.Settings.Default.myStrings = sc;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
    class MyStringsConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first requirement is easy to satisfy by changing type of your collection to ObservableCollection<string>. I don't get the second one -- why would you want to add new element on focus lost -- it would be quite non-intuitive behavior for user.

Comment: In the project settings there is only string or StringCollection, no ObservableCollection<string>. You are probably right about the unintuitivity, but I can change that once I know how the binding works.